# windows 2012 R2 cmdlet not running on windows 2012 R2

Tags: powershell

I am running a script from a windows 2012 R2 server, when I run get-printer its not recognised by powershell.

Get-printer is a windows 2012 cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try `Import-Module PrintManagement` before executing `Get-Printer`.
2. Also the Print Management Cmdlets are installed with the Print Server Feature, if this is not installed the Cmdlets are not available.